# Filter list dropdown based on another list dropdown within same form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a SharePoint list which has a drop down column called PM No - This is a list of numbers ranging from T1 to T200.

Each T number relates to different machines. I want to have the option, for when the user selects any of the choices in the 'PM' column, then the second 'Machine' column filters based on the T number.

For example, If T1 has Machine A and Machine G assigned to it, when the user selects T1 in the 'PM' column then the 'Machine' column will be filtered to only show the two options of Machine A and Machine G.

In the past I used InfoPath forms to create a filter, however SharePoint online no longer supports InfoPath. I have searched online extensively and can't seem to find an answer that fits this scenario.

If I select T1 from this drop down
[image]

Then this dropdown should only show Machine A and G which related to T1 in the previous dropdown and so on.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are trying to implement is generally known as "cascading dropdowns" and if you search for "[sharepoint online cascading dropdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%20online%20cascading%20dropdown)" you can actually find a lot of resources.

From a quick glance through some of the search results it seems to me that where you probably want to focus is using PowerApps to implement the cascading dropdowns.  At least that's the direction I would go in if I were trying to do that.